# SimplyJS and xml : get value of a key

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

Good evening,
My Pebble Watch project has evolved and I'm now using an official external API to make HTTP requests to get values. My previous question was concerning JSON, now I'm getting the results in XML format.
Here is the XML I get when I call the API :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <items>
      <item id="1234567">
         <author gender="man" country="France" region="Ile-de-France">myuser</author>
         <category>mycategory</category>
         <date>2010-08-23T05:48:51+02:00</date>
         <from />
         <text>THIS IS THE CONTENT</text>
         <comments_flag>1</comments_flag>
         <short_url>http://myshort.url</short_url>
      </item>
   </items>
   <comments />
   <active_key>1234567890</active_key>
   <code>1</code>
   <pubdate>2014-07-12T18:51:49+02:00</pubdate>
   <language>fr</language>
   <errors />
</root>
```

And this is what I have now in my SimplyJS script :

```
simply.on('accelTap' || 'singleClick', function(e) {
      simply.body("Loading...");
      ajax({ url: 'http://myAPIurl', type:'xml' }, function(data){
      simply.scrollable(true);
      simply.body(data);
    });
  //}
});
```

As a result, the full XML displays on my Pebble. But I would like to get **only** the content under the **< text >** section.
I've tried with some "data.text" selector, like in JSON, but I get objects errors.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution thanks to Pedrolane member of Pebble forums
Here is the single line I used :

```
var mytext = data.match(/<text>(.*?)<\/text>/)[1];
```

And to get a perfectly readable text, replace the '& quot;' text by '"' :

```
mytext = mytext.replace(/&quot;/g, "\"");
```

Reference : [Simply.JS Documentation](http://simplyjs.io/)